# Function declaration with auto using new C++11 syntax but with auto& and without ->

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, function-declaration, return-type-deduction

consider the function definition below:

```
auto& Fnc1() { return someNonLocalVariable; }
```

Return type is not explicitly specified by -> in this case.
But there is the & after auto keyword.
Does this guarantee that a reference is returned instead of copy of the variable?
Is this a supported language feature (returning reference)? 
With VS 2017, it works as I expect: Return a reference.
But I could not find any online source to verify.

Comment: This is how C++ works. If a function returns a reference, that's what it returns. There are no exceptions.

Comment: That's a C++14+ code. Not C++11. RVO is guaranteed since C++17.

Comment: usual syntax is  said to be
auto Fnc1() {...}
Without &.
I could not find any source that says I can use auto& beside auto in this context

Comment: [The source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction)

Comment: `auto` is for deducing the "base" type only, without [CV-qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) or references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct specification, and as Ron commented, became operational in C++14. C++11 did require trailing return type syntax (`->` after the parameters).

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) for more.

> In a function declaration that does not use the trailing return type syntax, the keyword `auto` indicates that the return type will be deduced from the operand of its return statement using the rules for template argument deduction.

See also [auto type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts) where they include an example using `auto&`. You can think of this as being the same set of rules for declaring variables using the `auto` keyword.